# Django: order set queries

Tags: django, foreign-keys, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I have following 3 models

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )


class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=True
    )


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        max_length=256
    )

    task_group = models.ForeignKey(
        TaskGroup,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=True
    )
    
    execute_at = models.DateField(
        blank=True
        null=True,
    )
```

I want to get task groups for a product and order the tasks for each task group by execute_at.
I can get all the task groups and all the tasks for a product by

```
product = Product.objects.first()
task_groups = product.taskgroup_set.all()
```

`task_groups` contains all the groups and all tasks for each group.
I can also do something like `task_groups[0].task_set.all().order_by('execute_at')`.
I don't know how to put together these queries and order the tasks of each group by `execute_at` in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prefetch() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) and specify the queryset for the prefetched objects (This is also better for efficiency as lesser amount of queries would be made to the database):

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


product = Product.objects.filter(pk=some_pk).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'taskgroup_set__task_set',
         queryset=Task.objects.order_by('execute_at')
    )
).get() # Change `.filter(pk=some_pk)` as per your implementation
```